# Matplotlib rescale figure size after setting xlim

Tags: python, matplotlib

The main problem is that after setting the xlim of the axis (in particular decreasing xmax from 512 to 50), the figure doesn't rescale to focus on the region of the new xlim (0 to 50). Instead, the plot in the figure is scaled smaller with big right margin after xmax although nothing gets plotted. Strangely this only happens when I save the figures in pdfs.

Here are screenshots of the two pdf images I generated. The first one is the original image without changing the xlim.

[image]

The second one here is the image by setting xmax to 50 from 512.

[image]

Here is part of my code:

```
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white') 
ax = plt.axes()
...
lines=ax.plot(*a, clip_on=False)
ax.set_xlim([0, 50])
...
pp = PdfPages(outfile + '.pdf')
pp.savefig(bbox_inches='tight')
```

What would be the right way to remove the extra right margin space after xlim?

Comment: Add some code that generates the data (fake is ok) and then the full, but *minimal* amount of code required to demonstrate this behavior. It would probably help to take screenshots at the same zoom-level too.

Comment: Why do you have `clip_on=False` in the plot call?  That is probably what is throwing the tight bounding box for a loop.

Comment: @tcaswell Ah right. That solved the problem! Thanks for the pointer.